# Watch for any akka actor to restart during a test

Tags: akka

In many of my unit tests, I create an actor, which sometimes creates other actors.  In the tests that verify the system works as expected under normal circumstances (rather than tests of failure conditions), I usually expect none of the actors to restart.

Is there a general way to check that no actor has restarted?  I feel the answer probably involves supervisors, but its not clear to me how I would modify the supervisor of an actor created in non-test code.

I think what I am looking for is to be able to say something like "watch the `/user` actor, and all descendants, and send this actor a message when that actor restarts."

If relevant, I am using akka 2.5 and java 10

Answer (score 0):

what is the value that a *no-restart* gives to you? shouldn't you take advantage of the supervision strategies and guarantee that under temporary failure conditions, the action that you want to do is eventually performed?

This is in fact a known design in distributed systems and is often called *The Error Kernel*. It is also one of the different patterns that Roland Kuhn talks about in his book [**Reactive Design Patterns**](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-design-patterns).

It consists in a stateful actor (encapsulating what could be the business logic of a module in your application) that requires to do some side-effect in a fail-safe way (i.e.: writing to a database). So for performing the side-effect it will spawn a child actor which will execute the action without blocking the parent, and in case it fails, it can take advantage of the supervision strategy to re-start and reattempt or give up. We often simulate that type of behaviour in our tests and that way we can verify that the application doesn't just blow up when the DB doesn't respond, but also to verify that it eventually can communicate with it.

This is, after all, a kind of subjective topic and of course, the previous example can be made arbitrarily complex. But the point is that, you are meant to have chosen Akka for its ability to helping you writing resilient systems. So **testing that it can survive in short-term failure conditions is going to give you much more value than the opposite**.